# Intercept all outgoing network traffic (MacOS)

Tags: macos, unix, networking

I'm trying to figure out if there is some intermediate storage location I can access periodically to acquire all outgoing network packets on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no intermediate storage. The simplest approach would be to create a network extension to create a pass-through network tunnel. This is not a trivial task and you should expect to generally understand unix networking and routing in order to attack this problem.

See [NetworkExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension) for documentation, and [SimpleTunnel](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimpleTunnel/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016140) for a full example.